# Help converting X, Y coordinates to Lat Long

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, latitude-longitude

I have a geojson file I cannot seem to convert to X, Y coordinates.

I've tried ogr2ogr and QGIS, with no luck.

Is there a better way to do this in QGIS than to just save the vector layer with the Mercator projection?

I'm also using the ogr2ogr conversion command:

```
ogr2ogr -f geoJSON -t_srs EPSG:3078 bay_test.geojson bay.geojson
```

Have also tried to Mercator.

The file is of Bay County, in Michigan.

A feature in the file looks like this:

```
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1, "PRECINCTID": "10", "NAME": "Auburn Precinct 1", "COUNTY": "017", "POP2010": 2087, "CODIST": "3", "SLDIST": "098", "SSDIST": "31", "LOCLDIST": "City of Auburn", "CONGDIST": "05", "SHAPE_area": 29419528.992700, "SHAPE_len": 27298.747018 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13202130.235438145697117, 769367.830145135521889 ], [ 13202142.064482729882002, 769367.802668161690235 ], [ 13202475.064554918557405, 769367.802668161690235 ], [ 13203430.033937625586987, 769357.131757743656635 ], [ 13203423.967676792293787, 768206.876922428607941 ], [ 13203423.440282836556435, 768106.878762848675251 ], [ 13203423.132294606417418, 768048.379864096641541 ], [ 13203423.061756689101458, 768035.08018597215414 ], [ 13203422.912888877093792, 768006.879783056676388 ], [ 13203422.890333145856857, 767802.476074412465096 ], [ 13203423.142547208815813, 767421.395799823105335 ], [ 13203423.357441794127226, 767095.123486489057541 ], [ 13203423.416086688637733, 767005.123666495084763 ], [ 13203423.419777628034353, 767000.12408659607172 ], [ 13203423.486624605953693, 766900.124286599457264 ], [ 13203423.575617209076881, 766765.123736388981342 ], [ 13203422.826356898993254, 766716.983658783137798 ], [ 13203422.805441584438086, 766715.631135240197182 ], [ 13203572.713278252631426, 766713.318557843565941 ], [ 13203717.769582625478506, 766711.081029511988163 ], [ 13203717.021142523735762, 766663.304714307188988 ], [ 13203715.300345439463854, 766552.818550765514374 ], [ 13203640.302956063300371, 766553.538693681359291 ], [ 13203636.628422729671001, 766317.566806703805923 ], [ 13203416.638295125216246, 766319.678843155503273 ], [ 13203418.81061689555645, 765390.144530974328518 ], [ 13204729.538392417132854, 765363.362678363919258 ], [ 13204728.40568470954895, 765105.912405870854855 ], [ 13204726.962118044495583, 764777.741310238838196 ], [ 13204726.337119292467833, 764364.035198681056499 ], [ 13202826.129715647548437, 764407.01657596975565 ], [ 13202174.807609502226114, 764602.260197952389717 ], [ 13202096.283324293792248, 764602.996745035052299 ], [ 13202094.820072624832392, 764603.010688573122025 ], [ 13202092.874128356575966, 764357.352551281452179 ], [ 13202091.297687940299511, 764287.025428161025047 ], [ 13202091.297687940299511, 764215.150161802768707 ], [ 13202091.075001377612352, 764130.272132739424706 ], [ 13201568.117549918591976, 764133.961839929223061 ], [ 13201027.11961616948247, 764133.721518889069557 ], [ 13200886.715943563729525, 764133.659593157470226 ], [ 13200756.618598774075508, 764133.600948266685009 ], [ 13200441.750462107360363, 764133.461512848734856 ], [ 13200240.879390750080347, 764133.254410244524479 ], [ 13199503.968134917318821, 764133.044436909258366 ], [ 13199330.472747, 764132.96733732521534 ], [ 13198086.666179500520229, 764132.415337115526199 ], [ 13197635.960470020771027, 764132.214796178042889 ], [ 13197345.960229814052582, 764132.086433574557304 ], [ 13197318.559530023485422, 764132.074130453169346 ], [ 13196981.067997, 764138.509074926376343 ], [ 13196753.504065647721291, 764142.848387114703655 ], [ 13196753.602080542594194, 764299.525813266634941 ], [ 13196754.543679710477591, 764369.306677639484406 ], [ 13196756.914902, 764596.912849724292755 ], [ 13196774.349250335246325, 765197.650657430291176 ], [ 13196779.811837833374739, 766027.051475659012794 ], [ 13196781.971856482326984, 766354.973227947950363 ], [ 13196787.315513771027327, 766767.027029827237129 ], [ 13196812.356064084917307, 767972.576209932565689 ], [ 13196813.46580595895648, 768026.01073232293129 ], [ 13196813.613443460315466, 768046.907180033624172 ], [ 13196813.800450958311558, 768057.964408576488495 ], [ 13196815.074234500527382, 768137.128046177327633 ], [ 13198518.999222315847874, 768151.199540346860886 ], [ 13201946.287315230816603, 768144.630901910364628 ], [ 13201946.470221690833569, 768231.09685430675745 ], [ 13201946.370156273245811, 768237.854140661656857 ], [ 13201945.876800958067179, 768271.098414719104767 ], [ 13201946.738839916884899, 768471.095964200794697 ], [ 13201946.884837, 768537.095258057117462 ], [ 13201946.899600751698017, 768543.851314097642899 ], [ 13201947.072664711624384, 768622.094677947461605 ], [ 13201947.080046586692333, 768628.850323885679245 ], [ 13201947.24941960722208, 768787.811210036277771 ], [ 13201878.367093458771706, 768788.51043763756752 ], [ 13201885.167440749704838, 768968.888603784143925 ], [ 13201885.586567208170891, 768980.015550032258034 ], [ 13201951.206514708697796, 768980.963710866868496 ], [ 13201946.259428147226572, 769061.447473786771297 ], [ 13201952.458972834050655, 769119.279543161392212 ], [ 13201951.402134396135807, 769368.247631177306175 ], [ 13202084.23569418862462, 769367.938002534210682 ], [ 13202103.798893250524998, 769367.89207086712122 ], [ 13202130.235438145697117, 769367.830145135521889 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 2, "PRECINCTID": "100", "NAME": "Bay City Ward 1", "COUNTY": "017", "POP2010": 3891, "CODIST": "6", "SLDIST": "096", "SSDIST": "31", "LOCLDIST": "Bay City Ward 1", "CONGDIST": "05", "SHAPE_area": 46265705.364600, "SHAPE_len": 31484.358680 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13258237.231163565069437, 767117.008695349097252 ], [ 13258237.466973461210728, 767097.244545243680477 ], [ 13258302.928620751947165, 767097.73174899071455 ], [ 13258321.791361898183823, 767097.872004620730877 ], [ 13258310.674668252468109, 767051.611844509840012 ], [ 13258301.984971065074205, 766962.496209099888802 ], [ 13258268.138664085417986, 766615.40946888923645 ], [ 13258258.279349815100431, 766513.524420037865639 ], [ 13258248.45981564745307, 766412.238943472504616 ], [ 13258245.694073148071766, 766390.981193989515305 ], [ 13258295.675518460571766, 766386.965043887495995 ], [ 13259018.573925022035837, 766301.932815656065941 ], [ 13259636.4389130435884, 766235.174829095602036 ], [ 13259677.006007105112076, 766234.78646045178175 ], [ 13259786.585840437561274, 766215.228182636201382 ], [ 13259785.881691586226225, 766177.944382533431053 ], [ 13259570.523690544068813, 764067.402343787252903 ], [ 13259566.489495854824781, 764021.862326599657536 ], [ 13259528.256714709103107, 764025.778001181781292 ], [ 13259137.051378354430199, 764069.854766704142094 ], [ 13258665.068644501268864, 764824.973417222499847 ], [ 13258586.922065231949091, 764830.807148993015289 ], [ 13258515.602079916745424, 764838.973553262650967 ], [ 13258212.634345959872007, 764847.262578681111336 ], [ 13258045.576773252338171, 764889.591070137917995 ], [ 13257917.072683148086071, 764893.97631399333477 ], [ 13257838.060373980551958, 764903.324638471007347 ], [ 13257088.280049398541451, 764986.199308678507805 ], [ 13256957.121355023235083, 765035.266221702098846 ], [ 13256965.275456167757511, 764674.016123995184898 ], [ 13255656.081470232456923, 764797.493567325174809 ], [ 13255188.076746791601181, 764848.509705454111099 ], [ 13254836.186866585165262, 764892.842786073684692 ], [ 13254537.968138877302408, 764923.835178159177303 ], [ 13254268.929963044822216, 764946.425356075167656 ], [ 13254008.528991065919399, 764976.34614597260952 ], [ 13253741.636890333145857, 765002.014975868165493 ], [ 13253373.432656273245811, 765038.570020869374275 ], [ 13253102.967317938804626, 765063.35343586653471 ], [ 13252853.496442209929228, 765090.839027218520641 ], [ 13252584.62435856461525, 765117.491697013378143 ], [ 13252328.09518002346158, 765145.087606385350227 ], [ 13251971.12780012562871, 765176.604521699249744 ], [ 13251693.37737137824297, 765209.941069200634956 ], [ 13251412.299357417970896, 765232.233511492609978 ], [ 13251115.107940647751093, 765267.134196281433105 ], [ 13250834.92600429430604, 765295.788584515452385 ], [ 13250555.255057729780674, 765326.467657014727592 ], [ 13250413.284377105534077, 765341.271187119185925 ], [ 13250256.155016168951988, 765352.727857120335102 ], [ 13250093.86531450226903, 765368.9897176399827 ], [ 13249958.032662939280272, 765380.238054722547531 ], [ 13249815.906142730265856, 765397.208165138959885 ], [ 13249676.017971064895391, 765409.854547329246998 ], [ 13249394.475309085100889, 765435.242045760154724 ], [ 13248805.143318459391594, 765488.383753784000874 ], [ 13248950.055266167968512, 766229.780728995800018 ], [ 13249498.998558044433594, 767401.473759613931179 ], [ 13249600.300028666853905, 767682.26757138967514 ], [ 13250859.606893252581358, 769220.787296183407307 ], [ 13254182.835154917091131, 770491.842414826154709 ], [ 13254394.742539502680302, 770509.613048575818539 ], [ 13254449.703059501945972, 770508.858456909656525 ], [ 13256654.573157627135515, 770478.570213682949543 ], [ 13258243.384366482496262, 770460.90210597217083 ], [ 13258242.037174291908741, 770028.972605660557747 ], [ 13258241.489685229957104, 769770.2994025349617 ], [ 13258241.354350857436657, 769708.398689724504948 ], [ 13258240.7982496060431, 769446.294965244829655 ], [ 13258240.579253979027271, 769342.263431176543236 ], [ 13258236.438842315226793, 769240.01297951489687 ], [ 13258236.465088982135057, 769177.97201107442379 ], [ 13258236.486414398998022, 769128.1619893014431 ], [ 13258236.507739815860987, 769077.971800968050957 ], [ 13258236.529475335031748, 769027.971900969743729 ], [ 13258236.551210854202509, 768977.971590869128704 ], [ 13258236.562693770974874, 768950.971152745187283 ], [ 13258236.577047418802977, 768917.971300765872002 ], [ 13258236.635282211005688, 768772.971590764820576 ], [ 13258239.21278689801693, 768702.854851074516773 ], [ 13258239.171776480972767, 768669.984592013061047 ], [ 13258237.231163565069437, 767117.008695349097252 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 6, "PRECINCTID": "220", "NAME": "Bay City Ward 5", "COUNTY": "017", "POP2010": 3874, "CODIST": "5", "SLDIST": "096", "SSDIST": "31", "LOCLDIST": "Bay City Ward 5", "CONGDIST": "05", "SHAPE_area": 27569269.439300, "SHAPE_len": 30014.328865 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13253241.988529399037361, 757185.71909274160862 ], [ 13253241.353278044611216, 757150.795442119240761 ], [ 13253252.599154502153397, 756829.817163474857807 ], [ 13253256.853985231369734, 756460.338735766708851 ], [ 13253261.803532417863607, 756054.81256190687418 ], [ 13254584.439502626657486, 756060.889895558357239 ], [ 13254586.634790230542421, 755874.401587426662445 ], [ 13254586.874701168388128, 755860.490443989634514 ], [ 13254587.089185647666454, 755835.8042236790061 ], [ 13255902.009045958518982, 755817.127259723842144 ], [ 13255907.987134397029877, 755533.912603057920933 ], [ 13255927.07297220826149, 754675.538335554301739 ], [ 13255929.464289605617523, 754519.147982329130173 ], [ 13254749.593781895935535, 754519.891911283135414 ], [ 13254689.544689398258924, 754521.788232952356339 ], [ 13253336.90795898064971, 754527.172900661826134 ], [ 13253305.457480542361736, 754520.101884618401527 ], [ 13253308.178111586719751, 754379.400066286325455 ], [ 13253330.312663771212101, 753509.600706808269024 ], [ 13253334.166412625461817, 753290.210561595857143 ], [ 13253359.521922938525677, 753222.367849513888359 ], [ 13252446.743236690759659, 753228.988161079585552 ], [ 13251386.103543668985367, 753222.81281253695488 ], [ 13251238.819143354892731, 753224.405657120049 ], [ 13250763.372669711709023, 753221.027218990027905 ], [ 13250767.342478044331074, 752796.17693680524826 ], [ 13250770.795145023614168, 752426.723935551941395 ], [ 13250774.126831270754337, 752070.162968888878822 ], [ 13250778.391094397753477, 751613.80684419721365 ], [ 13250786.028464294970036, 750965.058961905539036 ], [ 13250797.54747012630105, 750395.982016079127789 ], [ 13250803.499722, 750022.605138160288334 ], [ 13250544.73301512748003, 750121.509960032999516 ], [ 13249743.228712625801563, 750440.380713365972042 ], [ 13249538.330418355762959, 750521.72815565764904 ], [ 13248662.782218668609858, 750873.880502536892891 ], [ 13248672.874472104012966, 751530.076286599040031 ], [ 13248675.926057208329439, 751710.356437847018242 ], [ 13248677.821148563176394, 752137.816212847828865 ], [ 13248674.692463874816895, 752502.208528682589531 ], [ 13248678.30794221162796, 752860.055992119014263 ], [ 13248680.046783875674009, 753228.797052532434464 ], [ 13248682.868300542235374, 753630.773774825036526 ], [ 13248687.187927730381489, 753982.800219722092152 ], [ 13248692.283472, 754206.416078262031078 ], [ 13248691.080226376652718, 754336.70125076174736 ], [ 13248696.363598354160786, 754687.042987741529942 ], [ 13248848.018478773534298, 754687.204158678650856 ], [ 13248979.976876273751259, 754687.344414308667183 ], [ 13249375.294327106326818, 754686.552503161132336 ], [ 13249369.637760333716869, 755041.069100558757782 ], [ 13249355.656899187713861, 755394.90820586681366 ], [ 13249354.472928460687399, 755659.730510868132114 ], [ 13249351.566110126674175, 755699.78333430737257 ], [ 13249352.0652068965137, 755759.946435764431953 ], [ 13249322.390069399029016, 755759.141401283442974 ], [ 13249303.78610398247838, 756113.710492014884949 ], [ 13249299.612883981317282, 756468.355041906237602 ], [ 13249291.039246272295713, 756820.408553682267666 ], [ 13249281.06059169024229, 757171.51718544960022 ], [ 13249457.612075854092836, 757168.312221385538578 ], [ 13249743.8200828358531, 757171.37487930804491 ], [ 13249990.204924710094929, 757168.121522948145866 ], [ 13250188.220440752804279, 757162.393187947571278 ], [ 13250349.357749711722136, 757160.476361073553562 ], [ 13250613.583353146910667, 757163.89334899187088 ], [ 13251124.00884148105979, 757173.406125240027905 ], [ 13251120.621381063014269, 757519.568490661680698 ], [ 13251397.915363878011703, 757524.182572640478611 ], [ 13251680.946703981608152, 757536.379070557653904 ], [ 13251963.560558043420315, 757542.964523263275623 ], [ 13251959.210993252694607, 757889.849492222070694 ], [ 13251957.128484293818474, 757907.264565661549568 ], [ 13251958.982975333929062, 758042.698595970869064 ], [ 13252246.747737731784582, 758047.208511494100094 ], [ 13252538.462623458355665, 758049.804060764610767 ], [ 13252816.106425125151873, 758052.564471907913685 ], [ 13253236.797430854290724, 758061.878347635269165 ], [ 13253235.72787918895483, 757905.1303835734725 ], [ 13253243.356226794421673, 757625.134224407374859 ], [ 13253241.988529399037361, 757185.71909274160862 ] ] ] } },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify EPSG:2898 as **source** CRS, so use `-s_srs EPSG:2898 -t_srs EPSG:4326` to convert from that to lonlat degrees on the command line.

In QGIS, use `Set Layer CRS`, to set the data to the corrrect CRS before saving the layer to some other CRS with `Save As ...`.

You can always load an Openstreetmap background layer with the QuickMapServices plugin to see if your data is placed correctly:

[image]

If the data appears on a wrong spot on Earth, reprojecting won't help, only correcting the layer's CRS will do.

Answer (score 5):

Luckily, your data has enough information to identify its location (Bay City, Michigan). Checking the various coordinate reference systems used in Michigan, it looks like the data is using the Michigan South State Plane zone (international feet). The geographic CRS is impossible to identify beyond that it's NAD 1983 or one of its re-adjustments/realizations.

Try EPSG::2253 (NAD 1983) or EPSG::2898 (NAD 1983 HARN)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying and failing. I used this command for either projections: `ogr2ogr -f geoJSON -t_srs EPSG:2898 bay_test.geojson bay.geojson` but it fails. Says: ```Failed to reproject feature 0 (geometry probably out of source or destination SRS).
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer OGRGeoJSON (use -skipfailures to skip errors)```

Comment: I don't know qgis. Add the details of what you're doing to the question.

Comment: OK. That's a command line though. But will update.